# Tableview cells disappear upon scrolling down an up except for the last cell from each section which turns grey color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

[image]

I am creating a tableview programmatically which is not a problem,
but making a programmatic table view cell is being a headache, it is the first time I do this.
I don't know what I am doing wrong as much as I have tried, I cannot debug this.

Here is the code for the view controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension CountryPhoneCodeList {
    class ViewController : UIViewController {
        
        var viewModel: ViewModel!
        
        var router: Router!
        
        private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
            let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
            table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            table.dataSource = self
            table.delegate = self
            table.register(CountryPhoneCodeListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountryPhoneCodeListCell")
            table.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            table.estimatedRowHeight = 44
            table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            table.separatorStyle = .none
            return table
        }()
        
        
        var updateTextFieldCode : ((String, String) -> ())? = nil
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            self.configureUI()
        }
    
        private func configureUI(){
            view.addSubview(tableView)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        }
    }
}

extension CountryPhoneCodeList.ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedViewModel = viewModel.cellViewModelAt(section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)
        updateTextFieldCode?(selectedViewModel.flag, selectedViewModel.countryPhoneCode)
        router.dismiss()
    }
}

extension CountryPhoneCodeList.ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return viewModel.countryCodeListCellViewModels.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let character = viewModel.getAlphabetCharacterFromIndex(index: section)
        guard let countryCodesStartingWithCharacter = viewModel.countryCodeListCellViewModels[character] else {fatalError("Could not get codes starting with letter \(character)")}
        return countryCodesStartingWithCharacter.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 14, y: -8, width: 50, height: 50))
        label.text = viewModel.getAlphabetCharacterFromIndex(index: section)
        label.customise(for: .bodyBold)
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryPhoneCodeListCell", for: indexPath) as? CountryPhoneCodeListCell {
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.cellViewModelAt(section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    
}

class CountryPhoneCodeListViewController : CountryPhoneCodeList.ViewController {}
```

And this is the code for the tableview cell

```
import UIKit

struct CountryPhoneCodeListCellViewModel {
    var countryName = ""
    var countryPhoneCode = ""
    var flag = ""
}

class CountryPhoneCodeListCell: UITableViewCell {
    private var countryNameLabel: UILabel = .buildBodyLabel()
    private var countryPhoneCodeLabel: UILabel = .buildBodyLabel()
    
    var viewModel: CountryPhoneCodeListCellViewModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let viewModel = viewModel else {fatalError("Cannot unwrap viewModel")}
            countryNameLabel.text = viewModel.countryName
            countryNameLabel.customise(for: .body)
            countryPhoneCodeLabel.text = viewModel.countryPhoneCode
            countryPhoneCodeLabel.customise(for: .body)
        }
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        countryNameLabel.text = nil
        countryPhoneCodeLabel.text = nil
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(countryNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(countryPhoneCodeLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: .constant16),
            countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: .constant16),
            countryNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: .constant4),
            countryPhoneCodeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: .constant16),
            countryPhoneCodeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: .constant16),
            countryPhoneCodeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: .constant16)
        ])
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning a new `UITableViewCell()`, not the dequeued one, `cell`. Does changing this fix the issue?

Comment: @SanzioAngeli No, this code worked when I was using a storyboard, I do if let cell first, if I remove return UITableViewCell it won't compile because the method must return a cell and I have to unwrap the cell, also the numbers go off the screen.

Comment: @AntonioRoldan - difficult to help, because there is so much in your code that we know nothing about. However, what *might* be the issue is: in your cell class, your first constraint has `equalTo: self.topAnchor` where it should be `equalTo: contentView.topAnchor`. If that doesn't help, look at [mre].